# Understanding PBKDF2 password encryption

Tags: android, password-encryption

I'm trying to understand how to store a user password using `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1` taking [this](http://nelenkov.blogspot.jp/2012/04/using-password-based-encryption-on.html%20%22%22) blog as reference. I can encrypt a message with a password determined by the user according to that implementation.

So, user creates a password, then I encrypt a determined message with the given password and store in SharedPrefs with `MODE_PRIVATE` the vi, salt, the cipher text and the message I encrypted.

Now, the user wants to access the app using the previously stored password, so using the stored vi, salt, cipher text and the entered password I get the message again. If decrypted message it's the same as the stored message the password is correct and I can proceed.

Is this the right way to do it? I have read a lot about storing password in Android but I still have this doubt about it.

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/scottyab/secure-preferences, should help you to understand.  hths!

Comment: I believe that blog post is targeted at generating encryption keys from passwords, not necessarily storing the password encrypted itself.  This is to encrypt other sensitive information that the app stores without the app knowing all the information to decrypt it.  I see at the beginning he mentions "authentication information", but this could be in reference to cached session tokens.